# Android ListView clears when starting an external Application

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter

In my Android Application I'm using a ListView to get to the specific View which shows additional information and functions.
Everything is working good but when i start the Phonecall function or open a Weblink (this 2 functions are available in the specific View) and then get back to the Application by pressing the back Button twice, the ListView is empty!

This does not happen when I'm using internal function like Google Maps or any other internal function from the specific View.

I guess there are some problems with the Adapter or Cursor.
I've only seen a `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but I'm not changing any Data. I Just want it to be shown again.

Here is the Order -> ListView -> select a Single View -> for example start a PhoneCall -> get back to the Single View via Backbutton -> get back to get ListView via Backbutton and it's empty!

---

```
// public replacing function for ordering the views
public void replaceView(View v) {
    history.add(v);
    setContentView(v);
}
// function that is called when the back button is pressed, controlling the views stack
public void back() {
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        history.remove(history.size() - 1);
        if (history.size() > 0) {
            setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
// remove site from stack and go the last view (Overriding Back Button)
@Override  
public void onBackPressed() { 
    FrontPage.group.back();
}
```

this is how the back button is defined. `onPause()` and `onResume()` are not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your `ListView` in `onPause` and rebuild it in `onResume`.
Both Methods must be overridden in your `Activity` class.

Comment: ah okay, Adil thank you for that Post, I will try it later on

Comment: This doesn't help me because I am not pausing the ListView.
I am starting the external App from the specific View and not out of the ListView. 
All Data in the specific View is loaded correctly but when I return to the ListView via it's empty.

Here is the Order -> ListView -> select a Single View -> for example start a PhoneCall -> get back to the Single View via Backbutton -> get back to get ListView via Backbutton and it's empty!

Comment: If you Start a Activity (e.g. your Phonecall) the Activity is set to the Background and your Dialer Activity is in the front. In this case the onPause() Method of your Activity is called and onResume() will be called as soon as you close the Dialer an your Activity apperas back on the screen.

Comment: So it does not matter from where I start the Phonecall? The onPause() method is called when started on SingleView aswell as from ListView ?
Thx for your reply